# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS XRDP terminates with There is no X server active on display 10

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, xrdp, rdp

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu desktop 22.04 and installed XRDP.

After entering my credentials, the connection just terminates. here is the relevant output from syslog:

```
Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] [session start] (display 10): calling auth_start_session from pid 5092

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5074]: [ERROR] sesman_data_in: scp_process_msg failed

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp[5091]: [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp[5091]: [INFO ] login successful for display 10

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5074]: [ERROR] sesman_main_loop: trans_check_wait_objs failed, removing trans

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp[5091]: [INFO ] loaded module 'libxup.so' ok, interface size 10296, version 4

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp[5091]: [INFO ] started connecting

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp[5091]: [INFO ] lib_mod_connect: connecting via UNIX socket

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: Started Session c7 of User username.

Nov 20 16:05:37 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5094]: [INFO ] Starting X server on display 10: /usr/bin/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%>

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [WARN ] Timed out waiting for X server on display 10 to startup

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] Session started successfully for user username on display 10

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5098]: [INFO ] Starting the xrdp channel server for display 10

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] Session in progress on display 10, waiting until the window manager (pid 5093) exits to end the session

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5093]: [WARN ] Timed out waiting for X server on display 10 to startup

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5093]: [ERROR] There is no X server active on display 10

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5093]: [ERROR] A fatal error has occured attempting to start the window manager on display 10, aborting connection

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [WARN ] Window manager (pid 5093, display 10) exited quickly (0 secs). This could indicate a window manager config problem

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] Calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 5092

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] Terminating X server (pid 5094) on display 10

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] Terminating the xrdp channel server (pid 5098) on display 10

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] X server on display 10 (pid 5094) returned exit code 1 and signal number 0

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] xrdp channel server for display 10 (pid 5098) exit code 0 and signal number 0

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5092]: [INFO ] cleanup_sockets:

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver systemd[1]: session-c7.scope: Deactivated successfully.

Nov 20 16:05:47 ubuntuserver xrdp-sesman[5074]: [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username username, display :10.0, session_pid 5092, ip ::ffff:192.168.1.101:59428 - socket: 12
Timed out waiting for X server on display 10 to startupNov 20 16:06:09 ubuntuserver wpa_supplicant[1219]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS

Nov 20 16:06:11 ubuntuserver systemd-timesyncd[1127]: Timed out waiting for reply from [2620:2d:4000:1::40]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).

Nov 20 16:06:21 ubuntuserver systemd-timesyncd[1127]: Timed out waiting for reply from [2620:2d:4000:1::41]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).


Nov 20 16:06:31 ubuntuserver systemd-timesyncd[1127]: Timed out waiting for reply from [2620:2d:4000:1::3f]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).

Nov 20 16:06:31 ubuntuserver systemd-timesyncd[1127]: Initial synchronization to time server 185.125.190.57:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).

Nov 20 16:07:25 ubuntuserver wpa_supplicant[1219]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS

Nov 20 16:09:07 ubuntuserver xrdp[5091]: [INFO ] connection problem, giving up

Nov 20 16:09:07 ubuntuserver xrdp[5091]: [INFO ] some problem
```

Comment: How is your server setup?  Is it running X and does it have some sort of RDP server running on it?  Are you certain that the Display on your server is set to :10.0 (obtainable by running `echo $DISPLAY` on your server but don't run it remotely as it will show you the display of your system)?  Please edit your question and add more details like that of your server setup to show that it is configured correctly as well.

Comment: sudo systemclt xrdp:echo $DISPLAY on the server shows :0

Comment: sudo systemclt xrdp:
     xrdp.service is active (running)

Comment: setting $DISPLAY to :10.0 throws the same error

Comment: Your server display is `:0.0` and not `:10.0`.  DISPLAY:10.0 is normally used by X11 Forwarding when using SSH.  You also need to make sure that your server is running X11 and not Wayland.  XRDP does not connect to Wayland.

Comment: 1) I explicitly disabled Wayland in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf "WaylandEnable=false"

2) removed setting the DISPLAY variable in .bashrc

3) restarted the server

4) from syslog
    xrdp-sesman[2383]: [ERROR] There is no X server active on display 10

Comment: /etc/rdp/sesman.ini contains this standard parameter: 
[Sessions]
...
X11DisplayOffset=10

Changing that to a different offset does not change the sequence of errors and ultimate failure

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:
In `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` I changed `allowed_users` to `anybody`, and the X server which is started earlier in the sequence will keep on running:

Change this:

`#allowed_users=console`

to this:

`allowed_users=anybody`